# Find out which list an item came from in python

Tags: python, list

Here is my code:

```
import random
from random import shuffle


a = ['cat','dog','fish','dolphin']
c = ['fridge','stove','microwave','oven']
b = ['cat','dog','fish','dolphin']
d = ['couch','chair','table','stool']

shuffle(c)
shuffle(d)

ac = a + c
bd = b + d

indices = random.sample(range(len(ac)),len(ac))
ac = list(map(ac.__getitem__, indices))
bd = list(map(bd.__getitem__, indices))

print ac
print bd
```

What this code does it randomize a bunch of lists so that a and b are put into the same order, and c and d are in their own randomized order. What I would like to do is create an if statement that states whether the item came from list a or c. For example, if ac = from list a, then print "congruent" or something like that. Is there any way to do this? Thanks. :)

Comment: since `ac = a+c` which is a short hand for merging 2 lists, `ac` will contain the whole `a` list along with the elements of list `c`, Wha do you want to achieve ? In this context `congurent` would be printed same number of times the length of the list `a`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'a' and 'c' do not contain the same members, simple membership testing should work:

```
for el in ac:
    if el in c:
        print('element ',el,' came from list c')
    else:
        print('element ',el,' came from list a')
```